# How to define a system call in Linux with non-default return type?

Tags: c, linux, macros, kernel, system-calls

I am trying to define a custom system call that traverses all the processes currently running.
The function declaration would look something like this:
`ssize_t traverse_process(struct customStructure *list, size_t length);`

I've found out that in order to define a new system call, we use the SYSCALL_DEFINEx macro (in my case 2).

However, I also read that the macro is actually equivalent to `asmlinkage long sys_traverse_process(struct customStructure *list, size_t length);`.

However, as you can see, my traverse_process' function declaration returns a ssize_t. Is there any way to define a system call without using the fore-mentioned macro?

Any help would be well appreciated!! Thank you.

Comment: Just a recommendation; if possible add an `ioctl()` instead. You could consider adding it to the handler for the root of `/proc` filesystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning `long` is the only **proper way** for a system call in Linux.

There is no way for a system call to return a value, which **size** differs from the size of `long`.

Do you expect `ssize_t` to have the same size as `long` on **all platforms**? If yes (this is a correct expectation), then there is no reason to prefer `ssize_t` over `long`. If you are not sure that your return type will fit to `long` on every platform, then you simply cannot use this return type.

For example, from the C standard you knows, that [read](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) function returns `ssize_t`. But `read` system call has `long` as return type (it is [defined](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.9.11/source/fs/read_write.c#L488) using `DEFINE_SYSCALL` macro):

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE3(read, unsigned int, fd, char __user *, buf, size_t, count)
{
    struct fd f = fdget(fd);
    ssize_t ret = -EBADF;

    if (f.file) {
        loff_t pos = file_pos_read(f.file);
        ret = vfs_read(f.file, buf, count, &pos);
        file_pos_write(f.file, pos);
        fdput(f);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Note, that despite on `long` being return type of the system call, the above implementation returns a value of type `ssize_t`.